# Changing TextMeshPro Text which is child of 2D Sprite via script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject, textmeshpro

I have a 2D square object sprite that has a child TextMeshPro object which stores a number.

Hierarchy in Unity:

[image]

Unity Scene:

[image]

I want to dynamically change the number in the TextMeshPro object via a script that is a component of the 2D square object. Below is the code I'm using.

'''

```
[SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI m_playerText;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    m_playerText.text = "8";
}
```

'''

However I am getting the error "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Would appreciate any feedback to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

Use `GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>()` for solve the problem:

```
void Start()
{
    m_playerText = GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();
    m_playerText.text = "some text...";
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error for some reason

Comment: Please include a photo of text Mesh Pro component .

Answer (score 0):

Has it already been mention nullReferenceExpection it means object is not been initiated to do that  try to
**  drag and drop the text TMP to player script Component**.

Comment: Do you mean to drag and drop onto the inspector tab of the player object?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).